# How does one obtain coordinantes from a map that was mapped by turtlebot in Rviz?

Tags: navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, coordinate, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to obtain coordinates from a map in Rviz? I tried using the code "rostopic echo /amcl_pose" to fnd its current position but that didnt work. Thats because a certain topic wasnt published but i couldnt find the topic for amcl_pose. How do i solve this? However from what I understand this gives the current position which leads to my followup question;

How do I get positions from a pre-mapped map without the turtlebot being there? Like is there a way to click on a point on the map and get that position?

Thanks for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338204/how-does-one-obtain-coordinantes-from-a-map-that-was-mapped-by-turtlebot-in-rviz?/) by [hamzaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/47667/hamzaay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can load your map properly and visualize it in RViz then you can use the **`Publish Point`** tool. This will publish the clicked point coordinates on the topic `/clicked_point`.

[image: image description]

Note that this will only publish the position of the clicked point. If you want to set orientation too then you can use some of the 2d Pose RViz tools or write your own plugin tool based on them.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1